# VBA Word: How to Save image/picture to Folder?

Tags: vba, ms-word, clipboard

I have the code to save the image in the word file. I use VBA Word but it gives an error. Please help me.

```
Sub SaveImage()

    
    Set clipboard = New DataObject
    Set Doc = ActiveDocument
    i = 1
    For Each Shp In Doc.InlineShapes
      If Shp.Type = msoLinkedPicture Or Shp.Type = msoPicture Or Shp.Type = wdInlineShapePicture Then
                Shp.Select
                Shp.Range.CopyAsPicture
                clipboard.GetFormat (2) 'jpg,bmp
                    strFile = "C:\Newfolder\file" & i & ".jpg"
                    SavePicture clipboard.getdata, strFile
                    i = i + 1
      End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not include links to your google drive in your question. Also, you did not explain what the error was, or on which line the error occurs.

Comment: I don't need export HTML and I export file word current.

Comment: With docx/docm files you don't need VBA - simply change the file extension to .zip, open the document as a zip archive, then extract the images. This can be automated, though. See my 'ExtractDocxMedia' macro in: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f2920489-1605-4eab-8781-c6cdc140426c/how-to-save-word-document-pictures-to-a-folder

Comment: What error do you get? Did you try to debug the code?